# Is there a VPN/Proxy that Admins cannot see at all?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy

So here's the rundown. My school does not allow any form of bypassing their web filter. They have some really trivial websites blocked that should not really be blocked that I would like to access but I'm afraid of what they will do if they see my encrypted traffic. They claim to be able to know exactly which computer is using a VPN/proxy and where on campus they are exactly.

So, first off, is it true that they would be able to know that it is my laptop doing the bypassing and know exactly where I am on campus?
Secondly, is there any possible way to make it so my traffic cannot be seen by the IT crew at my school or will they see it no matter what?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is completely off topic. Answers should not be posted.

Comment: @Xavierjazz Not quite sure how this is "off topic" or what "on topic" actually is but okay.

Comment: Read the FAQ. http://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Xavierjazz I read the F.A.Q. and my question appears to fall under the 2nd and 3rd topics to ask about. I don't see anywhere were it would fall under the what not to ask about. This is a networking and software (VPN/Proxy) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network admins, by nature, can see all traffic coming in and out the network. They might not necessarily *understand* the traffic (it might be obviously encrypted like HTTPS/TLS or SSH, or somehow disguised to not attract attention), but they can always see basic parameters such as 'source' and 'destination' IP addresses.

If you use a VPN or another kind of encrypted tunnel, it will disguise the destination address – only traffic from & to the tunnel server will be visible. But it's *still* your computer that communicates with the VPN server – the source address cannot be disguised (at least not without **cough** tampering with someone else's PC at the same school [and even that will buy you a week or two, at most]).

(Besides the above, VPN usage tends to look *very* obvious, unless you use it for very short amounts of time. Normal browsing causes short bursts of traffic to hundreds of different hosts on the Internet, while a VPN user will show up as communicating with the same 1–2 hosts for hours.)

Knowing your computer's IP address, if the admins have invested somewhat into the network, they can usually trace that address to a specific Ethernet port or a specific Wi-Fi radio, which narrows down your location to a specific room or two.

Additionally, if the network requires individual student passwords (as many universities do), then it also keeps an easily searchable log of "IP address X logged as user Y belonging to student Z".

Therefore, an 'undetectable' proxy might be *possible* but it would need to look similar to what the network already allows – not a VPN, but perhaps some web-based proxy that you only use for relatively short visits.

*(Source: I manage a school network, though I'm not nearly as paranoid.)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This pretty much sums up all the information that I was looking for and was very informative. Thank you very much.